# What would you call a person who invites people to his birthday party and eats foods himself

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

My friend who had his boss introduced to me the other day. He (friend's boss) has his birthday yesterday and we were both invited. My friend said we would surprisingly have fun watching his boss tomorrow at his birthday. And yes we did. His boss is a maniac.

What would you call a person who invites you and others for a party and then gorging most of the food himself and making you uneasy to grab on to something while still saying "come on have something" without even realizing what he is doing.

---

Added context from comments:

The host (the boss) is intruding on every bit of food that the guests want to put their hands on—like a glutton, making practically everyone disgusted by his unsophisticated-ness. He is digging into anything that we (3 invitees) attempt to or want to eat, so he appears rather crude, uncouth—"peasant like", at least as shown in movies. Nevertheless he isn't actually selfish per se, but he isn't aware of his quirkiness. "Glutton host himself" would be a perfect expression.

Comment: Even if the host is eating the lion's share, so long as the remainder is accessible and you're invited to partake, what's the cause of the unease?

Comment: The host (the boss) is intruding on every bit of food what the guest wants to put their hands on like a glutton making practically every one disgusted by his unsophisticated-ness. "Glutton host himself" would be perfect expression.

Comment: Do you mean that the host is marking *all* the food, say by grabbing the plate or touching each piece with his fork?

Comment: Ya you could say that - touching each piece with his fork. He is digging into anything what we (3 invitees) attempt to want to eat and which appeared as though "peasant like" who are rather crude, uncouth at least as shown in movies. Nevertheless he isn't actually selfish per se but he isn't aware of his quirkiness.

Comment: You could say that he is *eccentric*, or at least behaving so.

Comment: [**crass**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/crass) which means insensitive, and rude, but it is derived from Latin *crassus*, "thick" and "slow", which in modern Italian is now *grasso*, which means *fat*, significantly *overweight*, so with that  one word you can imply many things.  M-W has a fine list of [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crass) scroll down a bit.

Comment: This isn't personification, so that tag isn't right. It's not clear whether you are asking for a noun ("He is a...") or an adjective ("How ... he is!"): please add a sample sentence showing how you want to use the word or phrase.

Comment: I would call the guy "socially inept".  He likely behaves this way because his parents behaved this way and everyone in his family behaves this way.

Comment: I find his behavior as you describe it charmingly funny to be honest , a bit "larger than life" , in this case maybe a "larger than life appetite on display"

Comment: From what i have heard he is disinclined on giving a party but since it is a trend he forced into giving one and therefore he is inclined on having like Lawrence said eating lion's share but shamelessly of course. And yes he would do the same thing at some others party too as i have been informed. He likes to dominate a place and so does during food too. He is just 58 years old eccentric hyper self righteous person like people call him behind his back.

Comment: By the way, we have a new Interpersonal.SE site. Not saying that it should go there, but it's worth a consideration.

Comment: (1) Even before I saw HotLicks’ (HotLicks’s?) comment, I was thinking *socially awkward* or *socially oblivious*. (2) This might also almost be on-topic at [The Workplace Stack Exchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com), although I believe that they are oriented more to discussing behavior and less to discussing terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No word comes to mind to exactly describe this behavior, but there are several epithets that might apply:

- *philistine* (or capitalized *Philistine*)

  > a person who is lacking in or hostile or smugly indifferent to cultural values, intellectual pursuits, aesthetic refinement, etc., or is contentedly commonplace in ideas and tastes.
- *troglodyte*

> a person of degraded, primitive, or brutal character. ; a person unacquainted with affairs of the world.

- *caveman*

  > a man who behaves in a rough, primitive manner, especially toward women.
- other words are *barbarian*, *vulgarian*, *boor*, *lout*, *brute*, *uncivilized* (use these and a thesaurus to find more)

The philistine, troglodyte, and caveman references might be more applicable than the others, as the caveman types typically don't know any better or can't control themselves. This fits one of you parameters.

The other words hint that he should know better (or is capable of learning), but chooses to behave as he does anyway.

I would say the caveman references are stronger invectives than the others.

(Definitions from Dictionary.com)